# Form fields not moving up when focus on text feild in NativeScript+Angular application

Tags: forms, input, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, android-keypad

I working on Nativescript+Angular application and I am using RadDataForm    but when I am focusing on text field, text fields are not moving up. I am not sure how we can handle this.

If any one knows please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin [iqkeyboardmanager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager)

Note that you must use the scrollview component for wrap form.

Comment: I am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` for android

```xml
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Depending on the requirement you can set the value to either `adjustResize` or `adjustPan`, the difference (from [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)) being:

> **"adjustResize"**
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard on screen.
>
> **"adjustPan"**
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.